# win 8 metro app c# multiple itemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I working on a metro app and I have situation.
In one of my pages I used listview with a custom item template which displays an image and its name.
now I have to use 2 item template if image is vertical I have to use another template with longer height. can there be 2 different templates in o listview ? 
I must change the template in .cs something like 
`if the image is horizontal listview.ItemTemplate = 1 
else if the image is vertical listvew.ItemTemplate =2`
how Can I use this?

Comment: ItemTemplateSelector is what you need

Comment: how can I use it can you give me an example?

Answer (score 6):

First create a custom [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) class:

```
public class OrientationTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        // cast item to your custom item class
        var customItem = item as CustomItem;
        if (customItem == null)
            return null;

        string templateName = String.Empty;
        if (customItem.Width > customItem.Height
        {
            // image is horizontal
            templateName = "HorizontalItemTemplate";
        }
        else
        {
            templateName = "VerticalItemTemplate";
        }

        object template = null;
        // find template in App.xaml
        Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(templateName, out template);
        return template as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Define your item templates as resources (in my case in `App.xaml` - make sure you search for them in the right place inside template selector):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HorizontalItemTemplate">
        <!-- item template for horizontal image -->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="VerticalItemTemplate">
        <!-- item template for vertical image -->
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Add the template selector as resource as well (at the `ListView` level as below or anywhere higher, i.e. page or application level):

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <local:OrientationTemplateSelector x:Key="OrientationTemplateSelector" />
</ListView.Resources>
```

Now you can set it as [`ItemTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) to your `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource OrientationTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomItemsList}" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot man
I got 1 more question left
in c# I have a list and set the itemSourse of the listview to that list. now do I add them in a loop one by one?how am I going to call this class

Comment: also I get an error on  <local:OrientationTemplateSelector x:Key="OrientationTemplateSelector" /> where do I have code it in app.xaml or the xaml file where the listview in it?

Comment: @eomer What error are you getting? You need to put the line into `Resources` collection. I've updated the answer above. Also take care of namespaces: the prefix must point at the namespace with the class.

Comment: @eomer You won't be calling this class. You assign it to `ListView.ItemTemplateSelector` property as shown in the last line of my answer. You still need to set the `ItemSource` property to your list. I'm not sure what you're referring to by adding them in a loop.