# Selecting ItemTemplate from ViewModel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm developing a Windows 8 store app that contains a profile view. In the profile view I have a ListView that binds to an Observable collection of objects in the ViewModel. I also have a property in the view model called currentObject.

What I need to be able to do is select a different item template for the object in the collection that has the same id as currentObject. The method to do this in the viewmodel is simple, however, I'm unsure on how to fire the method and return the item template name to the listview template selector property in the view model.

I'm using c#, MVVM and caliburn.micro, so I would prefer to keep this code out of the code behind.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15354043/1822514

Comment: That should do the trick, thanks!

Comment: don't forget to upvote the linked answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this than using a DataTemplateSelector as shown in the answer in the comment above, if you are using DataTemplates in the XAML you can use the DataType attribute, you use this to associate the DataTemplate to a type (it should be a ViewModel). So when ever the type is encountered by the rendering engine it knows which data template to select.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
 </DataTemplate>
```