# How to make Datatemplate derive size from each item separately?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to fill `GridView` with images. I have `Datatemplate` for sizing images to fit the `GridView`. But there is a problem with this template. Image itself is surrounded with `Grid` within the template. When app runs, this `Grid` has width derived from first item in the `GridView`. So when images have different aspect ratio, all following items has template with same sizes as first item. Do I overlook something simple or I need to create something like trigger?

Data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplatePhoto" >
    <Grid Margin="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource PhotoListHeight}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Image Source="{Binding FullURL}" Stretch="Uniform" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0"/>                        
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need `TemplateSelector`. Check out [this so topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342851/win-8-metro-app-c-sharp-multiple-itemtemplate) for samples.